# Creating Word Documents - Win XP and WIn8

Tags: windows-8, ms-word, windows-xp

I build a function that creates a loooong word document (700pages++) then I Export it to `.pdf`.
This `WinXP` is a `VirtualMachine`
It works fine when I'm debbugin/running in WinXP. Also it's really FAST, like 3minuts.

But When I try the same code with Win8, the Formatation get a little messed up, also the time... IT gets more than 15minuts to accomplish the operation.

Why does it have this different with the same source code but only different SO ?

Comment: When you are running the same code with Win8, are you running the same EXECUTABLE (I hope not), or are you telling your compiler to optimize for Win8?

Comment: @user2654818 The same I guess... I just pass the project and run it!
Also, I build the `.exe` and run in both OS.... Why it's wrong ? Same code, generate same `.pdf`  I don't get it.

Comment: If you are just passing the project to a Win8 version of the same compiler, then maybe the optimization settings in the project are still set for WinXP.